# Bootstrap modal takes space even when closed or if changed all link colors change

Tags: html, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

if I use the code like this, then my links on my shop all suddenly have a blue color. Right now my links are black and I want them to stay like this.

If I delete the header from the code, my links are black again, but the modal
takes up all the space on the page (makes a huge blank white space) as if it would be open and the page goes at the bottom of the "open modal" which is actually close, but takes up all the space.

I am pretty new to coding, so I would really appreciate your help.

Thank you

```
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>

<body>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Launch demo modal</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://vmatechs.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/android.jpg" alt="image" />
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
 </div><!-- /.modal -->  
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
```

Comment: "If I delete the header from the code" -do you want to delete bootstrap css plugins?

Comment: This is used for a shopify store, so it should simply be a size chart pop up, when you click the text size chart. But if I add the code like this all my link colors change to blue, which doesn't match the rest of my page

Answer (score 1):

i can't tell you the exact code that you have to write but the issue is that: the bootstrap.min.css file is re-styling your link colors. here is the code that creates this problem:

```
a {
color: #428bca;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

so you have to override this style with adding a new one to your custom css file and be sure that your css file is imported to the page after bootstrap.min.css. for example let's assume that you have a custom css file called style.css. it must have a code block like that to make all the links black

```
a {
color: #000;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

and it must be imported in your html file like that:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
```

i guess this will solve your problem.

Comment: Hello, thank you so far, but where do I have to put this:a {
color: #000;
text-decoration: none;
} in the site_temp.scss.liquid? My buttons usually have normal edges, and if I add the modal the edges are a bit rounded. Do you know what to do about that?

Comment: I added the global.scss.css after the bootstrap.min.css but it doesn't work, it messes up my entire layout. What can I do?

Comment: i don't know your css structure but if this site_temp.css is loading after your bootstrap.min.css it is not important where you put the code. try putting it at the end of the file. button problem is the same. you are importing bootstrap styles with bootstrap.min.css and they are changing your sites style. so if you don't like these styles you have to override them by adding your own styles.

Comment: I had to add the style from the global.sccs.css and now the colors and bottoms are like the should be. The only problem left is, I have 2 dropdown menus in the topbar 1 with the account symbol and account next to it, and the other one with a currency symbol and the chose currency next to it. If I am on the products now, the account and curreny are both under the symbols and not next to them?  Why is that?